# C++ Modify base class without affecting inherited classes

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base class that is inherited by many other classes in different projects.  One project requires an addition to the base class. Unfortunately this then throws an error when I try to compile all the other projects.

Base class:

```
class MidiBase
{
    public:
    virtual void midiNoteOnReceived(unsigned char note, unsigned char velocity) = 0;
    virtual void midiNoteOffReceived(unsigned char note) = 0;
    virtual void midiClockStartReceived(void) = 0;
    virtual void midiClockStopReceived(void) = 0;
    virtual void midiSysexStartReceived(void) = 0;
    virtual void midiSysexDataReceived(unsigned char index, unsigned char data) = 0;
    virtual void midiSysexStopReceived(void) = 0;
    virtual void midiSysexWrite(unsigned char data) = 0;
    virtual void midiControlChangeReceived(unsigned char cc, unsigned char val) = 0;
    virtual void midiPitchBendReceived(char bend) = 0;
    virtual void midiProgramChangeReceived(unsigned char patchNum) = 0;  //THIS IS THE NEW LINE 
};
```

Example inherited class that doesn't need to use new line, but won't compile without it:

```
#include "Midi.h"
#include "MidiBase.h"

class OdyEngine : public MidiBase
{
//variables
public:
    static OdyEngine& getInstance()
    {
        static OdyEngine instance; // Guaranteed to be destroyed.
        return instance;
    }
protected:
private:
    Midi* midi_;  
    //functions
    public:
    const Midi* getMidiPtr() const { return  midi_; }
    Midi* getMidiPtr() { return midi_; }
    void midiControlChangeReceived(unsigned char anlControl_, unsigned char val);
    void midiNoteOnReceived(unsigned char note, unsigned char velocity);
    void midiNoteOffReceived(unsigned char note);
    void midiClockStartReceived(void){}
    void midiClockStopReceived(void){}
    void midiSysexStartReceived(void){}
    void midiSysexDataReceived(unsigned char index, unsigned char data){}
    void midiSysexStopReceived(void){}
    void midiSysexWrite(unsigned char data){}
    void midiChannelChanged(unsigned char channel);
    void midiPitchBendReceived(char bend);
    //void midiProgramChangeReceived(unsigned char patchNum){}  //WILL NOT COMPILE WITHOUT THIS
    protected:
    private:
    OdyEngine(OdyEngineBase* base);
    OdyEngine() {}
    OdyEngine( const OdyEngine &c );
    ~OdyEngine();
    OdyEngine& operator=( const OdyEngine &c );

}; //OdyEngine
```

Is there any way to add the new code to the base class without having to modify every inherited class that uses it, as I only require the new function for use in 1 inherited class.

Comment: It seems like you need to provide a default implementation for that new method. How should all the existing derived classes behave when the new method is called? If you can't answer that question, you may need to reconsider your class hierarchic. Perhaps introduce an intermediate class which inherits from `MidiBase` and adds only the new methods.

Comment: @paulsoulsby are you placing these in an array?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The default implementation would be "do nothing". I think for now I'll just update all the inherited class, as there's only about 8 of them. Was just thinking of approach if there were (e.g.) 100 of them!

Comment: @JakeFreeman no, it's a singleton class.

Comment: @paulsoulsby ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the no-op implementation to the base class, you won't need to add it in each of your separate projects.  Optionally, include an assertion to alarm if it's ever called without being overridden with a proper implementation:

```
virtual void midiProgramChangeReceived(unsigned char patchNum) {
    assert (!"Unimplemented function, please override with an implementation.");
}
```

A second option, which hides this function from projects that don't need it, is to #ifdef the code.  Enable it at compile-time for the project that needs it: `c++ -DENABLE_MINI_PROGRAM_CHANGE_RECEIVED myprog.cpp`.  The function won't exist in other projects; thus no one can mistakenly call it, and there's no overhead in virtual method tables.  The downside is #ifdef cruft in the code.

```
#ifdef ENABLE_MIDI_PROGRAM_CHANGE_RECEIVED
virtual void midiProgramChangeReceived(unsigned char patchNum) = 0;
#endif
```

It's off-topic, but also consider adding `override` to virtual methods in the inherited class:

```
void midiClockStopReceived(void) override {}
```

This replaces subtle misbehaviors with compile errors if you get the method signature wrong, or if it's ever changed in the future.  It's a winning improvement to C++11.

Answer (score 2):

An easy fix to your problem would be something like this:

```
virtual void midiProgramChangeReceived(unsigned char) { }
```

This way the no other derived classes have to implement it. However it is always better to just put the method in the derived class.

Comment: OK that's good to know. I may well do that then, was just interested to know if there was a way around.

Comment: Same effect, less typing:   `virtual void midiProgramChangeReceived(unsigned char /*patchNum*/) { }`  The variable is optional